# Convert arguments into new object parameter without cloning the object?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a new object with parameters from 'arguments', but I don't know
how to or even possible to convert it directly without cloning. Here's how it is possible using a clone:

```
function theClass(name, whatever) {
        this.name = name;
        this.whatever = whatever;
    }

// I need to use the arguments passed from this function but without using clone
// as shown.
function doSomething()
{
    function clone(args) {
        theClass.apply(this, args);
    }

    clone.prototype = theClass.prototype;

    return new clone(arguments);
}

// Usage expectation.
var myNewObject = doSomething("Honda", "motorbike");

console.log(myNewObject.name);
```

However, this suffers on performance because each time you call doSomething, you have to create a clone just to pass that arguments to be applied in it from theClass.

Now I want to pass that arguments without passing to a cloned object, but I don't know
how to convert it directly.

Any idea?

Note: As clarified by kaminari, the parameters passed are not strictly 'name' and 'whatever', but could be anything depends on the object I want to create. 'theClass' in the code is merely an example.

Thanks.

Comment: each function has an `arguments` array like variable in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: In light of the intended use of these functions:**

Probably your best option on maintaining your intended behavior is to implement your function in the following way:

```
function theClass(options){
   this.name = options.name || ''; //or some other default value
   this.whatever = options.whatever || '';
};

function doSomething(options){
   options = options || {};
   return new theClass(options);
};
```

With this implementation in mind, the code you supplied in "usage expectation" would look like this:

```
var myNewObject = doSomething({name: "honda", whatever: "motorbike"});

console.log(myNewObject.name);
```

In this manner, `theClass` can support as many or as few parameters as need be (only depends on what's supplied in the object and what you choose to extract from it) and similarly, the wrapper `doSomething` can be given as many or as few options as desired.

Comment: I tried yours but when I create new object from theClass through doSomething, the arguments are not passed (myNewObject.name is undefined). I've updated the code on how it is used.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code to better explain its use. Given that I don't know what restrictions you have on `doSomething`, I wonder if it would be possible for you to set variables--`var arg0 = arguments[0]`--from the arguments passed to `doSomething` and then just call `new theClass(arg1, arg2)`. I imagine that you're trying to maintain generality out to any number of arguments which is why you don't do that currently.

Comment: Yes, I try to maintain generality. The concept is that doSomething is a substitute of creating new object. For example, you can easily pass parameters like a = new A(a, b, c, ...), but in this case I want it a = doSomething(a, b, c, ...) while doSomething act as a wrapper to indirectly create A as an object. I've added a note to assume 'theClass' is just an example of any other form.

Comment: `apply` does take `arguments` objects as well. No need to copy them into an array.

Comment: Indeed you're right @Bergi, I had made an incorrect assumption about what wasn't working in the original code set. That said though, the original portion of my post doesn't answer Arly's question as he had intended anyway.

Comment: I started to think that this is kind of a design problem so I guess no right or wrong for answers, but I take this as a yes.

Answer (score 0):

> this suffers on performance because each time you call doSomething, you have to create a clone just to pass that arguments to be applied in it from theClass.

Simply define the `clone` function outside of `doSomething`, and it won't get recreated every time:

```
function theClass(name, whatever) {
    this.name = name;
    this.whatever = whatever;
}

function clone(args) {
    theClass.apply(this, args);
}
clone.prototype = theClass.prototype;
function doSomething() {
    return new clone(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I voted for ur answer, it's ok for my problem as it gives me performance in case cloned object is unavoidable.